Upgrade CompVis Autoencoder to PTL 2.2.2
I am trying to upgrade PTL to version 2.2.2 for latent-diffusion. Can someone help me understand the new way of training_step with optimizers. ? This line here throws error:
. RuntimeError: Training with multiple optimizers is only supported with manual optimization. Remove the optimizer_idx argument from training_step, set self.automatic_optimization = False and access your optimizers in training_step with opt1, opt2, ... = self.optimizers().
RuntimeError: Training with multiple optimizers is only supported with manual optimization. Remove the optimizer_idx argument from training_step, set self.automatic_optimization = False and access your optimizers in training_step with opt1, opt2, ... = self.optimizers().
[rank: 1] Child process with PID 3177085 terminated with code 1. Forcefully terminating all other processes to avoid zombies 

